# Broadcast Receiver is not working when pressing back (Back to already opened activity)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver

Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkStateChecker">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

this is the class

```
public class NetworkStateChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();


        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                new AutoTask().execute("start");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and when the asynctask is done i call this

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(act1.DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(act2.DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(act3.DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));
```

here is my sample in one of those activity

```
public class act1extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST = "website link";
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

        registerReceiver(new NetworkStateChecker(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

        //Codes here


        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //Codes here
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));
    }
}
```

here is the scenario. I will go to an activity do some stuff and return to the activity above after the broadcast receiver works. next is when i go to another activity and do some stuff there after pressing back the broadcast doesnt work

whats the problem? how can i fix it?

Comment: at which place you un register your broadcast ?

Comment: actually i dont have that :(

Comment: I think first you don't need to register network checker broadcast. Because you already register that in Manifest  registerReceiver(new NetworkStateChecker(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

Comment: i will try on it

Comment: Actually I don't get your question properly. Can you properly tell me what scenario you do and what problem you face ?

Comment: when i remove it even reopening the activity doesnt make the broadcast work

Comment: You have mentioned 2 broadcast 1 is CONNECTIVITY_ACTION and second is DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST What are you talking about ?

Comment: @SohelS9 the broadcast receiver works when the onCreate runs for ex. Intent from act1 to act2 but when i pressed back that means it will go back on the already opened activity now thats where the BR doesnt work

Comment: it is just a string that will be called to check if theres a net when accessing the site

Comment: here is my ref code https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-sync-sqlite-database-with-server/

Comment: It is not necessary when onCrate run so broadcast is run. Broadcast catch the action from everywhere from application. Condition is it must be registered...

Comment: it is registered the only problem im facing is that when going back to the already opened activity the BR doesnt work at all

Comment: @SohelS9 i dont know why it is not working when pressing back when intent it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189198/discussion-between-sohel-s9-and-myown-email).